# How to make a current showing list disappear after a new one appears?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

For my jQuery I have 3 images for different running events. When I click on the first image, a list shows, and disappears when I click again. For the middle image, a list slides down when I click, then slides up when I click again. For the third image, a list fades in when I click, and fades out when I click again. I have all of that down so far, but say for example the middle image list is showing. If I were to click on the first image, the list for the middle image should disappear, and the list for the first image appears. It is like that for all lists. I need help on getting one to disappear when I make a new one show. Here is my code so far.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>FV Runners</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="styles/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="styles/my_style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    // Hides the lists on load
    $('h3').hide();
    $('ul').hide();

    // Click on a picture to show the corresponding list

    // Hide/Show
    $("img[src='images/run1.jpg'").click(function(){
      $(this).siblings('#5k').find('h3, ul').toggle();
    });

    // Slide up/Down
    $("img[src='images/run2.jpg'").click(function(){
      $(this).siblings('#half').find('h3, ul').slideToggle();
    });

    // FadeIn/Out
    $("img[src='images/run3.jpg'").click(function(){
      $(this).siblings('#full').find('h3,ul').fadeToggle();
    });

  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="header">
    <h1>Fox Valley Runners Club</h1>
  </div> <!-- End of 'header' div-->

  <div id="main">
  </div>  <!-- End of 'main' div-->

  <div id="pics">

    <div class="race_box">
      <img src="images/run1.jpg" /><br />
      <figcaption>5k/10k Events</figcaption>

      <div class=".races "id="5k">
        <h3>5k/10 Events</h3>
        <ul>
          <li>Mini Sprint</br>10/30/20</br>Memorial Park</br>Appleton</li>
          <li>Iron Horse</br>11/06/20</br>Bay Beach Park</br>Green Bay</li>
          <li>Twilight Trail</br>11/13/20</br>River's Edge Park</br>Wrightstown</li>
        </ul>
      </div><!--  End of '5k' div-->
    </div> <!-- End of 'run1' div-->

    <div class="race_box">
      <img src="images/run2.jpg" /><br />
      <figcaption>Half Marathon Events</figcaption>

      <div class=".races "id="half">
        <h3>Half Marathon Events</h3>
        <ul>
          <li>Fox River Marathon 10/15/20</br>Pierce Park</br>Appleton</li>
          <li>N.E.W. Half Marathon 10/29/20</br>Bay Beach Park</br>Green Bay</li>
          <li>Winnebago Run 11/27/20</br>Menominee Park</br>Oshkosh</li>
        </ul>
      </div> <!-- End of 'half' div-->
    </div><!-- End of 'run2' div-->

    <div class="race_box">
      <img src="images/run3.jpg" /><br />
      <figcaption>Full Marathon Events</figcaption>

      <div class=".races "id="full">
        <h3>Full Marathon Events</h3>
        <ul>
          <li>Cheesehead Marathon 9/24/20</br>Pamperin Park</br>Green Bay</li>
          <li>Chain O'Lakes Marathon 10/29/20</br>Bay Beach Park</br>Green Bay</li>
          <li>Fox Cities Marathon 11/12/20</br>Menominee Park</br>Oshkosh</li>
        </ul>
      </div> <!-- End of 'full' div-->
    </div> <!-- End of 'run3' div-->

  </div> <!-- End of 'pics' div-->


</body>
</html>
```

Help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add a method to hide other element before opening the clicked element.
I added a method `hideEverything` which does what you want to accomplish. feel free to ask anything if you have any question.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Hides the lists on load
  $('h3').hide();
  $('ul').hide();
  // this will toggle(hide) everything except the element which is clicked.
  function hideEverything(elem) {
    $('.race_box').each(function() {
      let clicked = $(elem).siblings('div').attr('id');
      let currElem = $(this).find('div').attr('id');
      let visible = $(this).find('ul,li').is(":visible");
      if (visible && currElem != clicked) {
        switch (currElem) {
          case "5k":
            $(this).find('h3, ul').toggle();
            break;
          case "half":
            $(this).find('h3, ul').slideToggle();
            break;
          case "full":
            $(this).find('h3, ul').fadeToggle();
            break;
        }
      }
    })

  }

  // Click on a picture to show the corresponding list

  // Hide/Show
  $("img[src='images/run1.jpg'").click(function() {
    hideEverything(this);
    $(this).siblings('#5k').find('h3, ul').toggle();
  });

  // Slide up/Down
  $("img[src='images/run2.jpg'").click(function() {
    hideEverything(this);
    $(this).siblings('#half').find('h3, ul').slideToggle();
  });

  // FadeIn/Out
  $("img[src='images/run3.jpg'").click(function() {
    hideEverything(this);
    $(this).siblings('#full').find('h3,ul').fadeToggle();
  });

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>FV Runners</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="styles/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="styles/my_style.css" rel="stylesheet" />

</head>

<body>
  <div id="header">
    <h1>Fox Valley Runners Club</h1>
  </div>
  <!-- End of 'header' div-->

  <div id="main">
  </div>
  <!-- End of 'main' div-->

  <div id="pics">

    <div class="race_box">
      <img src="images/run1.jpg" /><br />
      <figcaption>5k/10k Events</figcaption>

      <div class=".races " id="5k">
        <h3>5k/10 Events</h3>
        <ul>
          <li>Mini Sprint<br>10/30/20<br>Memorial Park<br>Appleton</li>
          <li>Iron Horse<br>11/06/20<br>Bay Beach Park<br>Green Bay</li>
          <li>Twilight Trail<br>11/13/20<br>River's Edge Park<br>Wrightstown</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!--  End of '5k' div-->
    </div>
    <!-- End of 'run1' div-->

    <div class="race_box">
      <img src="images/run2.jpg" /><br />
      <figcaption>Half Marathon Events</figcaption>

      <div class=".races " id="half">
        <h3>Half Marathon Events</h3>
        <ul>
          <li>Fox River Marathon 10/15/20<br>Pierce Park<br>Appleton</li>
          <li>N.E.W. Half Marathon 10/29/20<br>Bay Beach Park<br>Green Bay</li>
          <li>Winnebago Run 11/27/20<br>Menominee Park<br>Oshkosh</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- End of 'half' div-->
    </div>
    <!-- End of 'run2' div-->

    <div class="race_box">
      <img src="images/run3.jpg" /><br />
      <figcaption>Full Marathon Events</figcaption>

      <div class=".races " id="full">
        <h3>Full Marathon Events</h3>
        <ul>
          <li>Cheesehead Marathon 9/24/20<br>Pamperin Park<br>Green Bay</li>
          <li>Chain O'Lakes Marathon 10/29/20<br>Bay Beach Park<br>Green Bay</li>
          <li>Fox Cities Marathon 11/12/20<br>Menominee Park<br>Oshkosh</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- End of 'full' div-->
    </div>
    <!-- End of 'run3' div-->

  </div>
  <!-- End of 'pics' div-->


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Glad it helped you! do upvote and accept the answer as well.